# How do I split a directory when a field changes in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

I'm creating a directory mail merge in Word 2010 using an xlsx file as the record source. One of my fields is "Manager". Most of the fields will be different on every line, but Manager will be repeated several times.

In my directory, I'd like to insert a page break every time Manager has a different value from the last record, essentially splitting the directory into "chapters".

Is it possible to do this in a vanilla mailer merge, or will I need to bring VBA into the mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this with a workaround in the end. I sorted the spreadsheet by Manager, and cleared the value of all but the first cell in each manager group. I then set this as Heading 1 in my mail merge, and formatted Heading 1 so that it inserted a page break before itself every time. Therefore each manager has a page break before itself, and the blank cells aren't reproduced in the mail merge.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it without modifying your Excel file is to set up your Mail Merge Main Document as a "Directory" type merge and insert the following nested field codes:

```
{ IF { MERGEREC } = 1 "{ SET sManager "{ MERGEFIELD Manager }" }{ sManager }" }{ IF { MERGEFIELD Manager } = { sManager } "" "<you have to insert a page break here>   
{ MERGEFIELD Manager }" }
Whatever other fields and text you need for each record{ SET sManager { MERGEFIELD Manager } }
```

Where all the {} are the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 in Windows Word.

However, it can take quite a long time to get that particular approach to work exactly how you need it, so you maywell be better off sticking with what you have.